# How to fix 'MountainCarEnv' object has no attribute 'seed'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Using the gym library to create the environment using this code block:

```
from envs import Maze
from utils import plot_policy, plot_tabular_cost_to_go, test_agent, plot_stats, seed_everything
import gym

env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')
seed_everything(env)
```

I looked into a tutorial and they did the wrote the same lines of code, but I got the following error (btw utils and envs is already included in the same location as the python file that Im working with):

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 3
      1 import gym
      2 env = gym.make('MountainCar-v0')
----> 3 seed_everything(env)

File ~\1MLRL Course\utils.py:218, in seed_everything(env, seed)
    209 def seed_everything(env: gym.Env, seed: int = 42) -> None:
    210     """
    211     Seeds all the sources of randomness so that experiments are reproducible.
    212     Args:
   (...)
    216         None.
    217     """
--> 218     env.seed(seed)
    219     env.action_space.seed(seed)
    220     env.observation_space.seed(seed)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\gym\core.py:241, in Wrapper.__getattr__(self, name)
    239 if name.startswith("_"):
    240     raise AttributeError(f"accessing private attribute '{name}' is prohibited")
--> 241 return getattr(self.env, name)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\gym\core.py:241, in Wrapper.__getattr__(self, name)
    239 if name.startswith("_"):
    240     raise AttributeError(f"accessing private attribute '{name}' is prohibited")
--> 241 return getattr(self.env, name)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\gym\core.py:241, in Wrapper.__getattr__(self, name)
    239 if name.startswith("_"):
    240     raise AttributeError(f"accessing private attribute '{name}' is prohibited")
--> 241 return getattr(self.env, name)

AttributeError: 'MountainCarEnv' object has no attribute 'seed'
```

Any idea?

Steps I took:

- Imported the utils, env and gym libraries to start.
- Tried to create the environment MountainCar-v0
- Followed the gym documentation: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/classic_control/mountain_car/
- Had no idea how to update the utils, gym or env libraries without breaking them.

Comment: There are large differences between different gym versions. Try to figure out what version your tutorial uses and downgrade yours, check how to update to newer versions, or find an up to date tutorial instead. (It will help to include both versions as additional information here)

Comment: As far as I know, changing the seed of an environment happens (and is passed through) by the `env.reset()` function. Like @Daraan said, check what version you are using and what said documentation suggests